# Asynchronous database lookups in Node.JS using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Not confident enough if this would be the correct 'node way' of writing `Promises`:

Essentially, there are two async database calls, the result from both of these calls has to be collected and used in rendering the `view`:

**Creating ...**

```
exports.getIndustryById = function(industryId) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Industry.findOne({
      value: industryId
}, function(err, industry) {
  if (err) {
    return reject(err);
  }
  return resolve(industry);
});
})
}

exports.getCountryById = function(countryId) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Country.findOne({
   value: countryId
  }, function(err, country) {
  if (err) {
    return reject(err);
  }
   return resolve(country);
  });
 })
}
```

**And using ...**

```
  exports.renderEditProfile = function(req, res, next) {
  var i, c;
  ct.getIndustryById(req.user.industry)
    .then(function(industry) {
      i = industry;

      return ct.getCountryById(req.user.country);
    }).then(function(country) {
      c = country;

      res.render('profile_edit', {
        profile: req.user,
        industry: i,
        country: c
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.status(500).json({'message': err});
    });
};
```

This works, but am I getting Promises right?

Comment: If you look at A+ Promises lib, they have some great integration with node. It also allows to convert a node-like asyn/callback function to return a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises benefit from the new ES6 syntax, making callbacks a bit compact. If you can use Node.js 4+, then by all means take advantage of the new syntax.

Your indents could need a bit of work. You're mixing 2-space and 4-space. It doesn't really matter which one you chose as long as you are consistent.

```
var i, c;
ct.getIndustryById(req.user.industry)
  .then(function(industry) {
    i = industry;
```

Instead of putting an outsider `i` and `c` to store the values temporarily until the last `then`, why not pass it through as a resolved value? That way, your functions don't need to use temporary variables.

```
exports.renderEditProfile = function(req, res, next) {
  ct.getIndustryById(req.user.industry).then( industry => {
    return ct.getCountryById(req.user.country).then( country => ({ country, industry }) );
  }).then( data => {
    res.render('profile_edit', {
      profile: req.user,
      industry: data.industry,
      country: data.country
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).json({'message': err});
  });
};
```

Alternatively, both requests don't seem to depend on each other. Therefore, it makes no sense to fire them sequentially. Suggesting you fire them in parallel, and use `Promise.all` to listen for the response.

```
exports.renderEditProfile = function(req, res, next) {

  const industryPromise = ct.getIndustryById(req.user.industry);
  const countryPromise = ct.getCountryById(req.user.country)

  Promise.all([ industryPromise, countryPromise ]).then(resolution => {
    res.render('profile_edit', {
      profile: req.user,
      industry: resolution[0],
      country: resolution[1],
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).json({'message': err});
  });

};
```

Comment: Very helpful comments. Really appreciate it. Thank you.